# Deploying a flask web app on google cloud that is always online

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to deploy a flask web app on google cloud run, the web app needs to run and be available 24/7 since I am using to scheduled sending emails every 6 weeks, allow file storage, and retains files persistently. I am using Orm sql-alchemy file based storage in the app.

I deployed on google cloud run. After deploying I register on the website then log in. After an hour when I try to log in I get an error, It seem the web app deployment is not configured to remember or store my employee log in files permanently.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Cloud Run is stateless. If you want persistence, you must combine another service such as database, cloud storage, etc. If you store data in a file within Cloud Run, you are actually storing the data in memory, which will be discarded when the instance is shut down. See this [link](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/storage-options) for options. Also, review Guillaume Blaquiere's answer.

Comment: In some cases, you can use web browser `cookies` and `local storage` to store information between requests. This is commonly done to store authentication information. Since your problem involves storing state between requests, look into this type of enhancement.

Answer (score 2):

There are different aspects to your questions

1. Always online application.

Cloud Run is always online! However, instances can be stopped. The next one that will start will take more time because of instance initialization (named cold-start). If you consider sometime higher latency, but responsive website, as always online, Cloud Run is the right fit for you.

Else, you can use the min instance parameter (but you will lost the cost benefit of Cloud Run especially if you have low or sparse traffic)

2. File storage retains persistently

Cloud Run is a stateless service. It means you can't store anything in it (or no longer that the instance lifetime. Because it's stored in memory, when the instance disappear, your in memory data, also).

You can't manage the instance lifecycle. Even if you set a min instance to 1 (to have always 1 instance up and running), this instance can be replace at any time (usually, once a week, for underlying infrastructure maintenance (like patching)).

Therefore, you have to store your file elsewhere. Cloud Storage is a great place to store your file, and Cloud SQL for your SQL data.

If you need a low latency access to your file, you can also use [Filestore mount](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-filestore)  (be careful, the smallest Filestore instance is 1Tb, $460 per month).

For easiest management, you can also mount [Cloud Storage as a directory](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse) in your Cloud Run instances. But keep in mind that is Cloud Storage behind the scene (some write operation are forbidden, and the latency is equal to Cloud Storage API call)

Comment: Would I have the same storage issue with kubernetes?

Comment: @NyikoMaswanganyi I recommend creating a new question. Only ask questions to clarify the current question/answer on Cloud Run. Kubernetes is much more complex and requires more details from you.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for all the advise.

Comment: If my flask app that is deployed on cloud run that is responsible for sending emails every 6 weeks to users in the database always execute? I used the schedule library in my python script to schedule a function that sends emails to always execute every 6 weeks.

Comment: You are in the cloud, use a Cloud Scheduler service to invoke an endpoint on your Cloud Run service to send the email. You don't need to run a server full time to send emails only every 6 hours. A better design could be to use a batch service (Cloud Run Jobs) to send the emails, and to keep the standard Cloud Run for web request.